# Using the uinput kernel module in Lisp/SBCL

Tags: linux, common-lisp, sbcl

is there currently any way to use the uinput kernel module in SBCL? I have not been able to find any library myself (except some Japanese[?] guy's github: https://github.com/quek/info.read-eval-print.cl-mayu/blob/master/mayu.lisp ) so I was wondering if anyone knew anything about that.

Am I supposed to use some kind of SBCL-specific package? Am I supposed to generate my own bindings for this using something like CFFI?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to say there is no finished library you can use.  However, that github repo seems to be a good place to look for ideas for making your own.